# How to apply AJAX for a particular field in contact form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a form in contact form 7 which has a drop down menu with values student and professional. I want to apply ajax in it to get the further values of student like name of university and which course he/she is pursuing. Hope I am clear with the problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign change event for that drop down and pass selected value to ajax call.

**Sample**

```
$("#contact_form_7 select").on('change',function()
{
    var selecteValue = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url : 'URL.php?selectvalue='+selecteValue
    });

});
```

Set other parameters for `ajax` call as per your need (i.e beforeSend,success,dataType etc).